# Modular Exponentiation of 2

Tags: c, modulus, exponentiation

I have written this code to calculate `2^n mod 10^9+7`. But sadly this function works only till `2^31` and afterwards all the answers are `zero`.
Can somebody shed some light why?

```
typedef unsigned long long LL;
const int MOD = 1000000007;
LL powmod(int a,int n)
{
    LL p=1;
    for(;n;)
    {
        if(n%2) p=(p*a)%MOD;
        if(n/=2) a=(a*a)%MOD;
    }
    return p;
}
```

Comment: What happens when `a` exceeds `MAX_INT`?

Comment: Just change `LL powmod(int a,int n)` to `LL powmod(LL a,int n)`.

Comment: BTW, your naming is inconsistent. It would better be `typedef unsigned long long ULL;` and `typedef long long LL;`.

Comment: @GregHewgill surely you mean "when `a * a` exceeds `MAX_INT`" since an `int` cannot exceed that...:) however I am not sure how it is still working up to 2^31, assuming he has 32-bit ints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Just change `LL powmod(int a,int n)` to `LL powmod(LL a,int n)`.

As squeamish ossifrage hinted at, with `int a`, the subexpression `a*a` is computed in `int` range and overflows "when `a * a` exceeds `MAX_INT`" (M.M), while with `LL a`, it is computed in `unsigned long long` range.